# Make a sql limit query work for all records in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you specify the number to a  sql limit method such that the limit is actually all records.  I want to have a scope with a flexible limit e.g.  `scope :females, ->(n) {where(gender: 'Female').limit(n)`. Using this scope how do I specify all records? Is there a better way than `females(Model.all.count)`?

Comment: I personally think that if you are going to pass the limit in then you might as well just do `females.limit(7)` because it is clearer and less cryptic than `females(5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `females(nil)` to not have limit clause applied.  This works because limit(nil) applies no limit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
scope :females, ->(n=nil) do
  if n.present?
    where(gender: 'Female').limit(n)
  else
    where(gender: 'Female')
  end
end
```

Then:

```
Yourclass.females(10)   #=> reuturn 10 female records
Yourclass.females       #=> reuturn all female records
```

Comment: Verbose. `scope :females, ->(n=nil) { where(gender: 'Female').limit(n) }` would also work the same